# When i have a NSMutableArray must i release all the objects also?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When i have a NSMutableArray with some custom class objects, declared

```
NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Must i also release all the objects in *list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting an object reference into a `NSMutableArray` will make the retain count for that object incremented, because the array retains every object.
When sending the `release` message to the array, it also send the same message to all the objects it references.

So in case you didn't retain them over the array, you shouldn't do anything more.

Answer (score 0):

No, when the array is released, all the objects in the array are sent a release message. So when the autorelease pool is released or drained, all the objects in the list will be released in this case.

Answer (score 0):

if you add an object in your `NSMutableArray`, it calls `retain` on that object. When you release the array , it will call release on **all of the objects** that it has because it called `retain` previously on the object when you added.

So you don't need to call `release` explicitly  on each object, One `release` it enough on **array** instance.

To understand the fundamental rules of memory management that you must abide by, read “[Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)”.